# Deploy angular js (front end) on s3 and Api's(Backend) on API Gateway

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dropwizard, aws-api-gateway

I want to make my website more secure. So i was thinking of deploying front end(using angular js) on s3 with aws cloudfront and all my api's(using dropwizard) in API gateway.

1. How to deploy angular ap on s3 bucket using cloudfront?
2. Is it possible to call api's from the s3 bucket?

i have researched on this but i get only for angular app and not the other part(calling api's from the s3 bucket).

Comment: You don't "call api's from the s3 bucket". The angular app runs in the user's browser. You would call the APIs from the browser.

Comment: What i wanted to say is If i deploy the angular app in s3 and run it in browser, would i be able to call api's(placed in elastic bean or api gateway) from the angular code. ex: when i submit a login form, can i call login api placed in api gateway fro angular app.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to? You should try it and come back here when you have an actual concrete issue you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THis should work without a problem. I have angular apps that are hosted as static s3 websites, calling back-end api's (both thru amazon api and other custom api endpoints running on ec2 instances).

SO yes, in a general sense this will work - if its not working for you, you could give us specifics about what you are trying to do, and what error messages you are getting.

Comment: Do you have any link which can help me in deploying the same way?

Comment: I am trying to do this but I am getting a 403 when calling an endpoint on my Elastic Beanstalk Env